# Find $\lim \mathbb{E} \frac{X_{n}^{2}}{\log(1+X_{n}^{2})}$

Tags: probability-theory

Consider $Z_{n} = \frac{X_{n}^{2}}{\log(1+X_{n}^{2})}$, in which $X_n$ denotes a Gaussian random variable with zero expected value and variance equals $1/n$. Now we want find 
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E} \frac{X_{n}^{2}}{\log(1+X_{n}^{2})}$.
I thought about find characteristic function of $Z_{n}$ and so it will be easy to find expectation. But I guess there should be easier approach. Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to calculate $E[Z_n]$, rather than $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E[Z_n]$? The problem seems set up to solve the latter, which also seems easier.

Comment: @Michael yes. I want to find limit of $E[Z_{n}]$

Comment: To start, you can get intuition by finding what happens when $X_n\approx 0$, and make an intuitive guess what your limiting expectation might be.  You can also get a useful bound by the inequality $\log(1+y) \leq y$ for all $y>-1$, which you might use to work towards proving your guess.

Comment: openspace: Since you accepted an answer based on the "identity" $E(X_n^2)=\int X_n^2dx$, how would you justify it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it could be cracked by real analysis method. For convenience note $X_n$ by $f_n$. Then $EX_n^2=\int f_n^2dP=1/n$, and $f_n\overset{P}{\to}0$.

For $\delta>0$, set $$M(\delta)=\sup_{|x|\leq\delta}\frac{x^2}{\log(1+x^2)}$$ $$m(\delta)=\inf_{|x|\leq\delta}\frac{x^2}{\log(1+x^2)}$$
Note that $$\lim_{\delta\to0}M(\delta)=\lim_{\delta\to0}m(\delta)=1$$

We estimate this formula separately
\begin{eqnarray}
\int\frac{f_n^2}{\log(1+f_n^2)}dP&=&\int_{\{|f_n|\leq\delta\}}\frac{f_n^2}{\log(1+f_n^2)}dP+\int_{\{|f_n|>\delta\}}\frac{f_n^2}{\log(1+f_n^2)}dP
\end{eqnarray}

Fix $\delta$, as $n\to\infty$, for the upper bound
$$\leq P\{|f_n|\leq\delta\}M(\delta)+\frac{1}{\log(1+\delta^2)}\frac{1}{n}
\to M(\delta)$$
for the lower bound
$$\geq P\{|f_n|\leq\delta\}m(\delta)
\to m(\delta)$$

Let $\delta\to 0$, so we proved
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}\frac{X_n^2}{\log(1+X_n^2)}=1.$$

By the way, actually we don't need $X_n$ to be Gaussian r.v.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77911/discussion-on-answer-by-xiaoda-qu-find-lim-mathbbe-fracx-n2-log1). The above is the canned message the system generates when a mod purges a comment thread. Anyway, it was flagged for becoming a bit long. It seemed to me that no new comments were coming. If anyone is inclined to revisit them, they can be viewed in the linked chatroom.

Answer (score 2):

The function $f(x) = \frac{x}{\log(1+x)}  = \int_{0}^{1} (1+x)^s \, ds $ is concave and increasing on $[0,\infty)$. So

$$ f(0) \leq \mathbf{E}\left[ \frac{X_n^2}{\log(1+X_n^2)} \right] = \mathbf{E}[f(X_n^2)] \stackrel{\text{(Jensen)}}{\leq} f(\mathbf{E}[X_n^2]). $$

The conclusion follows from the squeezing theorem by noticing that $\mathbf{E}[X_n^2] = \frac{1}{n} \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simpler proof that the limit is $1$ if you use Gaussianity of the $X_n$.

Wlog you may as well assume that $X_n = n^{-1/2}Y$, where $Y \sim N(0,1)$, since this does not change the expectation.

Now, since $\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{u}{\log(1+u)}=1$, it follows that $Z_n = \frac{n^{-1}Y^2}{\log(1+n^{-1}Y^2)} \to 1$ a.s.

Now, if we can show that $\sup_n Z_n$ is bounded above by an integrable r.v., then we are done since we can just apply DCT. To prove this, just note that $\frac{u}{\log(1+u)} \leq 1+u$, so that $Z_n \leq 1+n^{-1}Y^2 \leq 1+Y^2$.